# Is a naturalization certificate required as well as a valid passport for reentry into the United States from the Philippines

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, us-citizens, paperwork, philippines

I am a naturalized US citizen with a valid passport and I've heard rumors that trying to reenter the United States from the Philippines requires a naturalization certificate as well as the valid passport are these rumors true?

Comment: There is no mention of this on TIMATIC, and it would surprise me. Your US Passport is evidence that you are a US Citizen.

Comment: @Calchas indeed, the passport is a more secure document, and probably more easily seen by the border officer to have been stolen or revoked, so it is actually *better* evidence than the naturalization certificate.

Answer (score 8):

Definitely not true. A U.S. passport is enough.

Comment: Do you have any authoritative references for your claims?

Answer (score 2):

I found this document online which I think would answer your question. Click the hyper link to direct you to the exact document.

**[What is required to re-enter the U.S.](http://1.usa.gov/1I0nQmC)?**

All **U.S. citizens**, including children, must present a passport or other approved travel document when entering the U.S. by air. U.S. citizens can present a
passport, a NEXUS card at airports with a NEXUS kiosk, a U.S. military ID with travel orders, or a U.S. Merchant Mariner Document when on official
business.

U.S. citizens entering the U.S. at sea or land ports of entry are required to have documents that comply with the Western Hemisphere Travel Initiative, which
are a U.S. passport, a passport card, a trusted traveler card such as NEXUS, SENTRI, or FAST, or an enhanced driver’s license.